# Cleanup dupes in an array that contains arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array as follows

```
var myArray={};
myArray.students = [];
myArray.Professors = [];
var tmpArray1 = [];
var tmpArray2 = [];

for(var key =0; key<data.length; key++){
    tmpArray1.push(name: data.studentName,id : data.studentId);
    tmpArray2.push({name : data.profName,id :data.profId});   
    myArray.students.push({name: data.studentName,id : data.studentId});
    myArray.Professors.push({name : data.profName,id :data.profId);
}
```

This array contains dupes for both students and professors. I am trying to clean it by checking it with a temporary array   and pushing only those students and professors that have unique student id and prof it but it doesnt seem to be working correctly. I want the myArray to have unique students and professors

Comment: I use underscorejs for things like this, see if http://underscorejs.org/#uniq will do what you need.

Comment: I see four pushes and no checking in your example.

Comment: All examples I have seen use single dimensional arrays,so the check is done using $.inArray. How can I do the same but check that the studentId and studentName is the same?

Comment: @asawyer, [have you heard about lodash?](http://lodash.com/)

Comment: @zzzzBov I had not, looks interesting. Thank you!

Comment: Off-topic: if `myArray.Professors` isn't a constructor, it is considered better to start with lowercase: `myArray.professors`. And note that `myArray` is an object but not an array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `studentId` and `profId` are unique (instead of a pair of name and id), you could use something like

```
var myArray = {
        students: [],
        professors: []
    },
    tmpArray1 = [],
    tmpArray2 = [];

for(var key=0; key<data.length; key++){
    if(tmpArray1.indexOf(data.studentId) === -1) {
        tmpArray1.push(data.studentId);
        myArray.students.push({name: data.studentName, id: data.studentId});
    }
    if(tmpArray2.indexOf(data.profId) === -1) {
        tmpArray1.push(data.profId);
        myArray.professors.push({name: data.profName, id: data.profId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a distinct in your array, make this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = [
        { "profId" : 1, "studentId" : 1, "profName" : "John", "studentName" : "Jack"},
        { "profId" : 2, "studentId" : 1, "profName" : "Steve", "studentName" : "Mark"},
        { "profId" : 3, "studentId" : 3, "profName" : "Gabe", "studentName" : "Martin"},
        { "profId" : 2, "studentId" : 1, "profName" : "Steve", "studentName" : "Mark"}  
    ];
    var Professors = [];
    var Students = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(jQuery.inArray(data[i].profName, Professors) == -1){
            Professors.push(data[i].profName);
        }
        if(jQuery.inArray(data[i].studentName, Students) == -1){
            Students.push(data[i].studentName);
        }       
    }

    console.log("Professors:");
    for(var x = 0; x < Professors.length; x++){
        console.log("   " + Professors[x]);
    }
    console.log("Students:");   
    for(var z = 0; z < Students.length; z++){
        console.log("   " + Students[z]);
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo Tostes. I however, want to wrap the Professor and students in a wrapper- hence using the myArray wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an object since objects have unique keys.

```
var myObj={};
myObj.students = {};
myObj.professors = {};

for(var key =0; key<data.length; key++){

    myObj.students[data[key].studentId] = data[key].studentName;
    myObj.professors[data[key].profId] = data[key].profName;

}

console.log(myObj)
```